# Is Amex fraud protection better than Mastercards? (in terms of convenience)

Tags: credit-card

I use a Mastercard and one of my huge problems is their automatic "anti fraud" system. I buy a lot of stuff every year and often order things from all over the world. It's not unusual for me to buy expensive things in Europe and have them shipped here. Also, I travel a lot. For example, once I went on ABE books and bought like $20,000 in rare books from 15 different dealers and after about 5 of these transactions went through, Mastercard blocked the rest of the transactions, which caused a huge hassle for me. This happens over and over again. The automatic system is always blocking my card. It's infuriating.

I am considering switching to American Express. Will that be a better experience, or is it going to be similar to Mastercard?

(Note: this question pertains to standard American Express charge cards, not American Express-branded credit cards that come from banks).

Comment: Call the bank’s anti-fraud department, and tell them what you’re about to buy, and from whom…

Comment: @RonJohn I know stuff like that. That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, so won't post an official one. However, considering that Amex cards are usually branded as "travel" type cards I would expect their fraud protection especially with foreign travel to be smarter than average. I don't ever purchase things overseas but I have disputed a few charges on my Amex card and the process is VERY smooth and quick, with a resolution within one week. In general, you might want to look for a new card that is branded as one for travel or international purchases.

Answer (score 4):

The anti-fraud protections are generally managed by the issuers, not by the network. So it's not "Mastercard", but whatever bank issued your card. You may have a significantly different experience with a different issuer even on the same network, while having the same experience with the same issuer on different networks. So for example, if your card is from bank B - it doesn't matter if you switch from B's Mastercard to B's American Express, the anti-fraud systems and rules are likely to be the same. But if you switch from Bank B to Bank C, even if C's card is also a Mastercard, you will be under a different set of anti fraud rules which may trigger less for your cases.

That said, it is likely that your pattern of behavior will trigger anti-fraud protections with many issuers, and they will not tell you ahead of time (or at all) what would trigger their anti-fraud system. So you'll probably have to go with trial and error evaluation of multiple card issuers until you find the one that works best for you.

---

From the comments it is evident that you're confusing the *credit network* and *credit issuer* concepts.

There are several major credit networks: Visa, Mastercard, Discover, American Express, JCB, UnionPay. Different issuers may participate in multiple networks. For example, [US Bank](https://www.usbank.com/credit-cards.html) or [USAA](https://www.usaa.com/inet/wc/banking_credit_cards_main?akredirect=true) issue Visa and American Express cards, while [Chase](https://creditcards.chase.com/all-credit-cards?jp_ltg=chsecate_allcards&CELL=6PK7) or [Citi](https://citicards.citi.com/usc/Multi/Featured/default.htm?cmp=knc%7Cacquire%7C2004%7CFCP%7CCARDS%7CUNK%7CGoogle%7CBR&targetid=kwd-338297245663&gclid=CjwKCAjw0ZiiBhBKEiwA4PT9z8cceltXEl-T8WHWlP7MfGpzDDQDD0Y6gBcQBuiNWG_4glwzkySjyRoCDg0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&BT_TX=1&tab=all-cards) issue Visa and Mastercard cards.

The networks facilitate transactions moving from *processor* (the bank servicing the merchants) to *issuer* (the bank providing credit to the consumers, the one that provides the credit/debit/charge cards).

The network doesn't interfere with the transactions, it just moves them around and routes them. Networks have certain usage rules (managing how disputes are managed, how fees are split, how currency conversions are conducted), but that is all. Networks don't get involved in the individual transactions.

Fraud detection is about an individual transaction and is done by the service providers. That would be *processors* for merchants and *issuers* for consumers.

What's confusing you is that American Express (similarly to Discover, but as opposed to either Visa or Mastercard) is *both* the network manager and also both a *processor* for merchants and *issuer* for consumers.

For the purpose of my answer, American Express is just another bank you'd consider applying for credit from (charge cards are still credit). The fact that they *also* own their own network is irrelevant.

Comment: If you switch to Amex it's likely to be the issuer itself, right? I have seen other companies issue Amex cards but it seems relatively uncommon at least in the UK.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica they used to only issue cards directly, but now there are more and more bank issuers. In the US the US Bank (one of the major banks in the country) is issuing them, and also Wells Fargo AFAIK.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, its simply wrong. The automatic anti-fraud is implemented by Mastercard/Visa. Also, Amex doesn't use banks as payment processors, so your understanding is flawed at multiple levels.

Comment: @FiveBagger the fraud alerts on my Visa cards come from the issuing banks (in my case, Chase and Capital One).

Comment: @FiveBagger none of your claims is true. Having worked in the industry I do know a thing or two about how it works.

Comment: @RonJohn This is simply not true. For one thing, a bank has no way of knowing where the card is being used for one thing and other private information about the vendor which is essential to doing fraud detection. Only the credit card company has this data. To do fraud detection, Visa uses something it calls the "Visa Advanced Authorization" system and Mastercard has a similar system. See https://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit-cards/major-credit-card-networks-protect-against-fraud/ for a basic description. Though it might seem to you that it is Chase, you are just talking to a front end.

Comment: @littleadv See my comment to RonJohn. Doing fraud detection requires knowing private details about vendors, like their address, for example. All the bank (and you) know is the title of the vendor like "SUZYS FLOWER SHOP". Only Visa/Mastercard know the personal details of the vendor. Think about it: if a bank were to do fraud detection they would have to have the personal details of EVERY SINGLE VENDOR in the world that can charge the card, which is something like 10 million vendors. Credit card companies do not give access to that database to their merchant banks or to anybody else.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica First of all, only credit card companies do fraud detection because only they have the merchant data to do that. Secondly, the question is about Amex CHARGE cards which are only issued by Amex, not banks. It is true that there are Amex-branded CREDIT cards issued by banks (and always have the bank's name on them), but I am not asking about that kind of product.

Comment: @FiveBagger from my own personal experience in the UK, which I am sure does not fully describe the way things work worldwide: My own Visa card issuer does the fraud detection; and I have an Amex Credit card, not Charge card, that is issued directly by them and that I could choose to carry a balance on if I wanted.

Comment: @FiveBagger "This is simply not true."  I know who sends me text alerts and emails asking "Is this a valid purchase?"  I know who answers the phone when I call the number provided.  Hint: **it's not Visa**.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, I know you interface to your bank because they control you as the customer. But the fraud detection technology is not provided by your bank, it's provided by Visa. The guy who talks to you on the phone just simply logs onto Visa's system and has a few limited actions he can perform like putting a note on your account or unlocking hold.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica As I wrote earlier, it's simply impossible for a bank to do fraud detection because they do not have the detailed merchant data to do that. Only credit card company has that data. I know if you have a fraud issue you CALL your bank and they talk to you about and release the hold or whatever, but the bank does not in any way provide the fraud detection technology. They just log onto the mastercard/visa systems as users.

Comment: @FiveBagger if you know all this, then you should know the answer to your question.

Comment: @FiveBagger if you think you know all this, why are you asking questions? Let's go one by one: (1) *a bank has no way of knowing where the card is being used for* - not true, the issuer knows *exactly* where the card is used at (the merchant and the location, and many times the exact location to the street address). (2) *a bank has no way of knowing where the card is being used for* - which *is* the issuer, your bank (or whoever you got the card from). (3) *Though it might seem to you that it is Chase, you are just talking to a front end* - no, absolutely not. Every issuer has their own ...

Comment: ... decision making process. Visa/Mastercard are networks, the same way as Comcast is your cable provider, but doesn't decide what you see on each channel. (4) *if a bank were to do fraud detection they would have to have the personal details of EVERY SINGLE VENDOR in the world* - no, only the one you're currently at. That information is attached to the transaction and travels along from the POS where the card is swiped to your issuer for authorization and back. ...

Comment: ...  (5) *the question is about Amex CHARGE cards which are only issued by Amex, not banks* - that was not in your initial question, but doesn't matter to the answer. American Express as an issuer is just another bank for that matter. (6) *but the bank does not in any way provide the fraud detection technology. They just log onto the mastercard/visa systems as users* - this is just ridiculous. How do you imagine this works? Different banks have different risk appetites and appeal and service different types of customers, why would you think they don't control their own fraud detection?...

Comment: ... It's the issuer (bank) who extends the credit to you, why would you think they'd let someone else, some third party network infrastructure provider, assess and manage the risk?

Comment: @RonJohn How would I know the answer to my question? I have never had an Amex card, so I have no idea how good or how sucky their fraud detection system. I was hoping someone with a lot of experience with them and other cards would have tangible knowledge of whether I will face the same "fraud detection" problems I am experiencing with Mastercard or not. I feel like I am repeating myself.

Comment: @FiveBagger the banks don't generally disclose their antifraud algorithms for obvious reasons and your use case does follow a common fraud pattern. The best answer I can think of is the one I gave you: your current issuer doesn't work for you - try another one and repeat until you find the one that works. You don't have to accept my answer, but I doubt you'll get anything more useful than that. As to your ridiculous claims - maybe now that you've educated yourself a bit more you can remove the offensive and abrasive comments that you've left in response to someone trying to be helpful.